# Using Airflow ExternalTaskSensor to schedule dependent ETL DAGs

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm trying to do something rather common in ETL, but struggling to get Airflow to schedule it.  I have to ETL 2 years of data to start, and then trigger hourly incremental ETLs.  The 2 years must be done iteratively, say a day at a time.

My plan would be to have a day zero DAG that runs `@once`, loops over the 2 years of data, and then triggers an incremental DAG that runs `@hourly`.

I've tried to simulate this in the following code, where day zero runs once, and then incremental runs every 5 minutes (just for testing).  The day zero runs successfully, but the incremental ends up with each job *up_for_reschedule*.

```
# Airflow 1.10.12.
# Run dayzero once with no catchup, and incremental every minute.

from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.sensors.external_task_sensor import ExternalTaskMarker, ExternalTaskSensor
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

start_date = days_ago(1)

# run the day zero once, then start running incremental
with DAG(dag_id="dayzero_dag",
         start_date=start_date,
         schedule_interval='@once',
         catchup=False) as dayzero_dag:
    dayzero_task = DummyOperator(task_id="dayzero_task")
    dayzero_marker = ExternalTaskMarker(task_id="dayzero_marker",
                                        external_dag_id="incremental_dag",
                                        external_task_id="incremental_sensor")
    dayzero_task >> dayzero_marker

# once day zero has completed, run incremental every 5 minutes
with DAG(dag_id="incremental_dag",
         start_date=start_date,  # shouldn't matter
         schedule_interval='*/5 * * * *',  # every 5 minutes, though in reality this would be every hour
         catchup=False) as incremental_dag:
    incremental_sensor = ExternalTaskSensor(task_id="incremental_sensor",
                                            external_dag_id=dayzero_dag.dag_id,
                                            external_task_id=dayzero_task.task_id,
                                            mode="reschedule")
    incremental_task = DummyOperator(task_id="incremental_task")
    incremental_sensor >> incremental_task
```

Am I completely off base with this approach?  Any suggestions?